# Maintain x*x in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, math, optimization

I have the following `while`-loop

```
uint32_t x = 0;
while(x*x < STOP_CONDITION) {
    if(CHECK_CONDITION) x++
    // Do other stuff that modifies CHECK_CONDITION
}
```

The `STOP_CONDITION` is constant at run-time, but not at compile time. Is there are more efficient way to maintain `x*x` or do I really need to recompute it every time?

Comment: @molbdnilo The `x`changes inside the loop

Comment: could build an cache vector of x*x and iterate that vector.

Comment: @ynkdk Oops, I missed that because the rest of the line was so loud.

Comment: Computing an integer multiplication is really quick, so you should not bother. Cache considerations are much more important for performance (unless you are on a tiny embedded microcontroller, but then you won't use C++11).

Comment: BTW, you should edit your question to explain what compiler you are using, what compiler optimizations, what is the target processor...

Comment: Have you considered `x < sqrt(STOP_CONDITION)`?

Comment: What is the largest value of `STOP_CONDITION` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Note:* According to the [benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35918236/2920343) below, this code runs about 1 -- 2% slower than [this option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35916660/2920343). Please read the disclaimer included at the bottom!

---

In addition to Tamas Ionut's answer, if you want to maintain `STOP_CONDITION` as the actual stop condition and avoid the square root calculation, you could update the square using the mathematical identity

```
(x + 1)² = x² + 2x + 1
```

whenever you change `x`:

```
uint32_t x = 0;
unit32_t xSquare = 0;
while(xSquare < STOP_CONDITION) {
    if(CHECK_CONDITION) {
      xSquare += 2 * x + 1;
      x++;
    }
    // Do other stuff that modifies CHECK_CONDITION
}
```

Since the `2*x + 1` is just a bit shift and an increment, the compiler should be able to optimize this fairly well.

**Disclaimer:** Since you asked "how can I optimize this code" I answered with *one* particular way to *possibly* make it faster. Whether the double + increment is actually faster than a single integer multiplication should be tested in practice. Whether you *should* optimize the code is a different question. I assume you have already benchmarked the loop and found it to be a bottleneck, or that you have a theoretical interest in the question. If you are writing production code that you wish to optimize, first measure the performance and then optimize where needed (which is probably not the `x*x` in this loop).

Comment: would be worth profiling this: you've replaced one multiplication, with a multiplication and an addition!  CPUs are pretty fast at integer multiplication these days.

Comment: `xSquared += (x << 1) | 1` would be the same, right?

Comment: @YnkDK yes but as I just stressed in my answer and M.M also noted in the comment, you should really be measuring this to see you are not sacrificing the readability of your code for no reason at all. I'm fairly certain that no compiler will perform `2 * x + 1` using a multiplication and an addition anyway.

Comment: @M.M you are absolutely right: as with any optimization, measure first, optimize later. I edited my answer to stress this a little more.

Answer (score 4):

What about:

```
uint32_t x = 0;
double bound= sqrt(STOP_CONDITION);
while(x < bound) {
    if(CHECK_CONDITION) x++
    // Do other stuff that modifies CHECK_CONDITION
}
```

This way, you're getting rid of that extra computation.

Comment: I'm fairly sure a multiplication is WAY more efficient than a sqrt.
Edit: That edit changes a lot :) (moving the sqrt out of the loop)

Comment: `Math.Sqrt`? What language are you writing?

Comment: Besides there not being anything like `Math.Sqrt` in C++, it insteads add *another* calculation, one that is usually more intensive than a simple multiplication.

Comment: I squared it to get rid of the sqrt computation in hope of an easy way to maintain `x*x`

Comment: @AndersSchou note that `STOP_CONDITION` is a <s>compile-time</s> run-time constant, so it should only be calculated once <s>and you can even hardcode `STOP_CONDITION` --> `SQRT_STOP_CONDITION`.</s>

Comment: @CompuChip "The STOP_CONDITION is constant at run-time, but not at compile time."

Comment: @CompuChip Nope, the OP says it's a run-time constant not compile-time. Still your comment is valid because it can be calculated at run-time before the loop.

Comment: I can not see a reason for downvoting. This answer is totally correct and may be the best one

Answer (score 4):

I made a small benchmarking for **Tamas Ionut** and **CompuChip** answers and here are the results:

> **Tamas Ionut**: 19.7068

The code of this method:

```
uint32_t x = 0;
double bound= sqrt(STOP_CONDITION);
while(x < bound) {
    if(CHECK_CONDITION) x++
    // Do other stuff that modifies CHECK_CONDITION
}
```

---

> **CompuChip**:  20.2056

The code of this method:

```
uint32_t x = 0;
unit32_t xSquare = 0;
while(xSquare < STOP_CONDITION) {
    if(CHECK_CONDITION) {
      xSquare += 2 * x + 1;
      x++;
    }
    // Do other stuff that modifies CHECK_CONDITION
}
```

with `STOP_CONDITION = 1000000` and repeating the process `1000000` times

---

**Environment:**

- Compiler : MSVC 2013
- OS : Windows 8.1 - X64
- Processor: Core i7-4510U
  @2.00 GHZ
- Release Mode - Maximize Speed (/O2)

Comment: Maybe also useful to add the optimization level?

Comment: Is this with `-O3` and `-march=native` or which flag did you use?

Comment: The worst case condition in my case would be `STOP_CONDITION = 810000`

Comment: results are : 16.9581  ,  17.2271  in same order and same iteration count

Comment: BTW there was a wrong the stop_condetion in my post I corrected it

Answer (score 0):

I would say, optimization in *readibility* is better than optimization in *Performance* in your case since we are talking about a very small Performance optimization

The compliter can optimize a lot for you regarding Performance but readibility lies in the responsibility of the programmer

Answer (score 0):

I believe **Tamas Ionut** solution is better than that of **CompuChip** because we only have x++ inside the for loop. However, a comparison between uint32_t and double will kill the deal. It would be more efficient if we use uint32_t for bound instead of using double. This approach has less problem with numerical overflow because x cannot be greater than 2^16 = 65536 if we want to have a correct x^2 value.

If we also do a heavy work in the loop then results obtained from both approach should be very similar, however, **Tamas Ionut** approach is more simple and easier to read.

Below is my code and the corresponding assembly code obtained using clang version 3.8.0 with -O3 flag. It is very clear from the assembly code that the first approach is more efficient.

```
using T = size_t;

void test1(const T stopCondition, bool checkCondition) {
    T x = 0;
    while (x < stopCondition) {
        if (checkCondition) {
            x++;
        }
        // Do something heavy here
    }
}

void test2(const T stopCondition, bool checkCondition) {
    T x = 0;
    T xSquare = 0;
    const T threshold = stopCondition * stopCondition;
    while (xSquare < threshold) {
        if (checkCondition) {
            xSquare += 2 * x + 1;
            x++;
        }
        // Do something heavy here
    }
}

(gdb) disassemble test1
Dump of assembler code for function _Z5test1mb:
   0x0000000000400be0 <+0>: movzbl %sil,%eax
   0x0000000000400be4 <+4>: mov    %rax,%rcx
   0x0000000000400be7 <+7>: neg    %rcx
   0x0000000000400bea <+10>:    nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
   0x0000000000400bf0 <+16>:    add    %rax,%rcx
   0x0000000000400bf3 <+19>:    cmp    %rdi,%rcx
   0x0000000000400bf6 <+22>:    jb     0x400bf0 <_Z5test1mb+16>
   0x0000000000400bf8 <+24>:    retq   
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) disassemble test2
Dump of assembler code for function _Z5test2mb:
   0x0000000000400c00 <+0>: imul   %rdi,%rdi
   0x0000000000400c04 <+4>: test   %sil,%sil
   0x0000000000400c07 <+7>: je     0x400c2e <_Z5test2mb+46>
   0x0000000000400c09 <+9>: xor    %eax,%eax
   0x0000000000400c0b <+11>:    mov    $0x1,%ecx
   0x0000000000400c10 <+16>:    test   %rdi,%rdi
   0x0000000000400c13 <+19>:    je     0x400c42 <_Z5test2mb+66>
   0x0000000000400c15 <+21>:    data32 nopw %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
   0x0000000000400c20 <+32>:    add    %rcx,%rax
   0x0000000000400c23 <+35>:    add    $0x2,%rcx
   0x0000000000400c27 <+39>:    cmp    %rdi,%rax
   0x0000000000400c2a <+42>:    jb     0x400c20 <_Z5test2mb+32>
   0x0000000000400c2c <+44>:    jmp    0x400c42 <_Z5test2mb+66>
   0x0000000000400c2e <+46>:    test   %rdi,%rdi
   0x0000000000400c31 <+49>:    je     0x400c42 <_Z5test2mb+66>
   0x0000000000400c33 <+51>:    data32 data32 data32 nopw %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
   0x0000000000400c40 <+64>:    jmp    0x400c40 <_Z5test2mb+64>
   0x0000000000400c42 <+66>:    retq   
End of assembler dump.
```